# Is ther any way I can attach this servo attachment to a normal DC motor?

Tags: motors

I would like to use a small dc motor as a winch for a hobby project. I found a budget winch attachment on Aliexpress but it only attaches to hobby servo motors.

A servo motor has a 25t (teeth) 6mm output drive. I cannot seem to find any equivalent coupling anywhere. The reason I want to have a dc motor instead of a servo is to have my own control board and a rotary encoder on the motor shaft.

Is there any way I can have a coupling or shaft for this?

If anyone has a budget alternative for Winch like attachment, it is also welcomed.

Here is the attachment :
[image]
[image]

Comment: your search term could be *external spline* or *hobby servo spline 25 tooth* ... Though the only thing I could find that has the external form is [this](https://www.gobilda.com/25-tooth-spline-servo-gears/) adapter to a larger gear... I like the flange idea in an answer below

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can most certainly couple that to a shaft.  Several methods come to mind:

Bolt a flanged coupler into the side of your winch.

Fit something into the gear location.  It is just aluminum so you could go for a hex shaft and heated thermoplastic (or even epoxy).  If you get a hex or square shaft just the right size, you could even deform the gear space to your shaft.

Comment: I like the flange idea. If epoxying something in, using a torx drive bit to get more grip in the epoxy is a potential trick

Answer (score 0):

If you are really desperate, you can always sacrifice a servo with a compatible attachment (take it apart), in order to get the shaft.
Then on the other shaft create a surface that you can use a DC coupling. E.g. like the following brass shaft couplings

[image]

Comment: Good Idea, I may also buy a servo and replace the motor in it.

Comment: You can also just buy splines adapter hubs if you know the right place...like ServoCity https://www.servocity.com/servo-hubs/

Answer (score 0):

I would forget about the servo interface, and just put a threaded rod through it with nuts and maybe a serrated washer or piece of rubber for grip.

Or you could use an arbor press to press a shaft into the pulley. If the shaft isn't perfectly smooth it should have decent grip.

Or you could heat the pulley and use thermal expansion to get it onto the shaft. When it cools it will clamp on with a lot of force.

Or you could just turn a new pulley on a lathe. it looks pretty simple?